# Trees and priority queues

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

I'm trying to solve an exercise which results to be a little bit difficult since I have to implement a priority queue starting from a template class of a tree (kind of RedBlack or BinarySearch Tree).

Using the template which looks like

```
class Node
  int key
  Node left
  Node right
  Node parent
  int leftNodes
  int rightNodes
```

Initially, when I had to insert a new element I tried to fill completely a level of the tree and then using an InOrderTreeTRaversal/Sort algorithm filling an array and generating a BinarySearch tree from that array and replacing with the new root element the original one. Supposing to have as a result a balanced tree.

Unfortunately this approach appears inappropriate since the tree must emulate the *maxheap property* maintaining *balanced* the tree for every insertion/deletion (and my code didn't work well in filling completely a tree level). It is possible implements a Tree with Heap capabilities? I mean a tree for which each element is bigger or equal its children, remains balanced after insertion and has autobalancing capabilities when the root node (the bigger key element) is deleted?

Comment: [Red Black Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Using a RedBlack Tree is possible to have on the tree the element ordered by value? ROtating the structure when adding or deleting lead to a disordered tree. I need to have the biggest element at the root and level by level node less or equal to its parent.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to implement a binary heap, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap

IIRC one of the main advantages of this data structure is that it can be embedded in an array (because of the balanced nature). Heapsort uses this kind of data structure to sort in-place.

Comment: Yes it is true, the purpouse is to design something like a binary heap. But instead of an array for storing the nodes I have to use the class node presented in the answers.

Comment: Sorry about being confusing. The linked Wikipedia article describes the algorithm for the tree form, see "insert" and "delete" sections. Embedding in an array is just an optimization that is not relevant here (but it contributes to the significance of this data structure).